# how to apply serial number in model.py in python django

Tags: python, django

we have a table that contains row and column we need one more column that will show serial number of row. It mean when user will update the table the serial number will update automatically.

```
class result(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(null=False,max_length=300)
   field1= models.CharField(max_length=300)
   field2 = models.IntegerField()
   field3 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   field4 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   field5 = models.CharField(null=False,max_length=300)

 def __str__(self):
   return self.name
 class Meta:
    ordering = ['name']
```

Comment: Is the serial number the primary key of the table or is the serial number just another IntergerField?

Comment: not a primary key ...it must have a number . when user will add or delete the record it will automatically update the count.

Comment: You're gonna need to include the code for your current model

Comment: i undated the code. and as of now i haven't add serial number because i don't know how to add and where i have to add this field

Comment: When you say the user deletes the record it will update the count? could you elaborate

Comment: count mean serial no. let say we have 4 row 1. 2. 3. 4. if user will delete the row 2 then 3 row become 2 and 4 become 3. Ultimately the S.no will update. I like to again clarified the question i want to show one column that will show the serial no. like 1 to n where n is the number of row. where and how to defined this serial no. filed. Is it i have to defined like name filed1 etc as shown in the code ??